# Jquery image slider works perfectly from right to left, but from left to right I cannot get it centered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on my photography portfolio display/gallery slider.

I already have half working prototype, but I cannot for life figure out why it centers images perfectly in one direction but not the other :S

http://jsfiddle.net/K88Yg/3/

Interestingly if I resize window and call my move_slide() function second time it goes to right place... so what is happening? can anyone shed light?

I believe this is quite a quirky problem. So fresh pair of eyes can help me allot.

So far my code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {


    //
    function set_slide_width(add_extra) {
        if (!add_extra) {add_extra = 0;}
        var slide_width = 0;
        $("#barely_slide article img").each(function(){
            slide_width += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
        $("#barely_slide article").css("width",slide_width + add_extra);
    }
    //
    set_slide_width();


    //
    function move_slide() {
        var focus_margin = 0;
        var img_real_height = 0;
        //
            var add_extra = 0;
            //var prev_deduct = 0;
        //
        $("#barely_slide article img").each(function(){
            //
                //if ($(this).attr("class") == "previous") {
                //  var theImage = new Image();
                //  theImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
                //  var img_real_width = theImage.width;
                //  var img_real_width_padding = img_real_width + ($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());
                //  prev_deduct = img_real_width_padding - $(this).outerWidth();
                //}
            //
            if ($(this).attr("class") == "focus") {
                    var theImage = new Image();
                    theImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
                    var img_real_width = theImage.width;
                    var img_real_width_padding = img_real_width + ($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());
                    img_real_height = theImage.height;
                    //
                        add_extra = img_real_width_padding - $(this).outerWidth();
                    //
                focus_margin += img_real_width_padding / 2;
                return false;
            }
            focus_margin += $(this).outerWidth();
        });
        //
            set_slide_width(add_extra);
        //
        var container_center = $("#barely_slide").outerWidth() / 2;
        var offset = container_center - focus_margin;
        //console.dir(offset);
        $("#barely_slide article").animate({"margin-left": offset }, "fast");
            //
            var img_height_offset = (img_real_height / 2) - 150;
            $(".focus").animate({"height":img_real_height,"margin-top":-img_height_offset}, "fast");
    }
    //
    move_slide();


    //
    var resize_timeout;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resize_timeout);
        resize_timeout = setTimeout(function(){    
            move_slide();
        },100);
    });


    //
    $("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "focus") {return false;}

        //
            $("#barely_slide article img").removeClass("previous");
            $("#barely_slide article .focus").addClass("previous");
            $(".previous").animate({"height":300,"margin-top":0}, "fast");
        //

        $("#barely_slide article .focus").removeClass("focus");
        $(this).addClass("focus");
        move_slide();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution that works better. You only have to change to `move_slide` function:

```
function move_slide() {
  var focus_margin = 0;
  var img_real_height = 0;
  var add_extra = 0;
  $("#barely_slide article img").each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("focus")) {
      var theImage = new Image();
      theImage.src = $(this).attr("src");
      var img_real_width = theImage.width;
      var img_real_width_padding = img_real_width + ($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());
      img_real_height = theImage.height;

      add_extra = img_real_width_padding - $(this).outerWidth();

      focus_margin += img_real_width_padding / 2;
      return false;
    /***************** This is where the changes begin *************************/
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("previous")) {
      // If has the previous class, calculate the width with a height of 300.
      var shrinked_width = 300 *  $(this).width() / $(this).height();
      // add the padding.
      var img_width_width_padding = shrinked_width + ($(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width());
      // then update the focus_margin
      focus_margin += img_width_width_padding;
    } else {
      focus_margin += $(this).outerWidth();
    }
    /***************** This is where the changes end ***************************/
  });
  set_slide_width(add_extra);

  var container_center = $("#barely_slide").outerWidth() / 2;
  var offset = container_center - focus_margin;

  $("#barely_slide article").animate({"margin-left": offset }, "fast");

  var img_height_offset = (img_real_height / 2) - 150;
  $(".focus").animate({"height":img_real_height,"margin-top":-img_height_offset}, "fast");
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLB/4/

Answer (score 1):

I explored your code and discovered that you are doing some maths before the first image (the one with the class `focus` get resized. That's influencing your maths. I saw that when clicking on the image who is already focused, the right contain was moving, but not the left. That is the key to your solution.

You are moving your image and it get centered. But then, you resize your last focused picture, that is what moving your content to the left.

My fastest solution is to call the calcul after the first img resize. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/K88Yg/4/

It is probably not the effect you want, i just wanted to show you what was the problem.

My fix was only to call the "moving" function after the animate `complete`.

```
$("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".focus").animate({"height":300,"margin-top":0}, {
        duration : "fast",
        complete: function(){
            $("#barely_slide article img").removeAttr("class");
            $this.addClass("focus");
            move_slide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that before a `complete` function, you need to save the `this` value into a variable.

**EDIT:** I did 2 or 3 hack to achieve the result you want. Here the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K88Yg/5/

And here a list of what I changed:

The function click :

```
$("#barely_slide article img").removeClass("previous");
$("#barely_slide article .focus").addClass("previous");
var oldStyle = $(".previous").attr('style');
$(".previous").css({"height":'300px',"margin-top":0}  )  
$("#barely_slide article .focus").removeClass("focus");
$(this).addClass("focus");
move_slide();
$(".previous").attr('style', oldStyle)  
$(".previous").animate({"height":'300px',"margin-top":0}, "fast");
```

I am saving the current CSS and then change them before the calcul. After the calcul, im am setting the old CSS back and do the animation.

By doing that, i had a little glitch where sometime the last image was wrapping. Discovered that was the function `add_extra`. So I saved the old extra and did a little condition:

```
if(old_extra > add_extra)set_slide_width(add_extra);

var container_center = $("#barely_slide").outerWidth() / 2;
var offset = container_center - focus_margin;
$("#barely_slide article").animate({"margin-left": offset }, {duration : "fast", complete : function(){
    if(old_extra < add_extra)set_slide_width(add_extra);
}});
```

If the old extra is higher it change the width before the animation. If it is lower, it wait until the animation is done. No more wrap glitches.

**EDIT2 :** Check [Chango answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16527927/2324107). He did the math calcul allowing you to do the exact same thing than the code above, but with less code.

Comment: I also had that kind of solution, but animation looks bad. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did a serries of hack to do what you wanted to do. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: fantastic... yes add_extra function was for that last image falling out problem :) thanks for your help really, with my jquery knowledge it was hard for me to find solution for this problem, though I did understand what was going wrong :)

Comment: That's great if you understand what's going on. Also, check [Chango's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16527927/2324107), he did the maths I didn't wanted to do. I would guess that his way is the optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is quite simple, the problem is in this method:

```
$("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "focus") {return false;}

    //
        $("#barely_slide article img").removeClass("previous");
        $("#barely_slide article .focus").addClass("previous");
        $(".previous").animate({"height":300,"margin-top":0}, "fast");
    //

    $("#barely_slide article .focus").removeClass("focus");
    $(this).addClass("focus");
    move_slide();
    return false;
});
```

The problem is that you are moving your slide before $(".previous") has finished to be animated. The consecuence is that if ".previous" is to the left of ".focus", then the focus_margin is misscalculated.

Here is the solution:

```
$("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "focus") {return false;}

    $("#barely_slide article img").removeClass("previous");
    $("#barely_slide article .focus").addClass("previous");

    var $image = $(this);
    $(".previous").animate({"height":300,"margin-top":0}, "fast",
        function () {
          $("#barely_slide article .focus").removeClass("focus");
          $image.addClass("focus");
          move_slide();
        });


    return false;
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle with some other modification: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLB/2/

The modifications:

```
$(this).hasClass("focus")
```

is better than

```
$(this).attr("class") == "focus"
```

And:

```
add_extra = add_extra || 0;
```

is better than

```
if (!add_extra) {add_extra = 0;}
```

I'll edit to add more details later.

Comment: This answer works just fine, but I have added another answer that looks better.